# Basic JSON Formatting for C3.js when data loaded via URL using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, d3.js, c3.js

Using Rails, how do you set up a controller to render JSON in a format that C3.js will accept?

Is there a special way to set up the data attribute in the c3.generate function call on the front end?

Answer (score 3):

Based off of [this example](http://c3js.org/samples/data_url.html):

Rails Controller should render JSON data like this:

`render json: { 'data1' => [30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250] }`

Javascript should look like this:

`<script type="text/javascript">
  var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#yourchartid',
    data: { url: '/controller/action.json', mimeType: 'json' },
  });
</script>`

I was missing the `mimeType` in the javascript. Hope this is helpful to someone starting out with C3.js and Rails!